# Rails 3 geocoder and the filtering an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geocode

I'm trying to get the geocoder gem to work on an object that has been filtered using a has_many relationship

like so

```
user.rb
has_one :profile
has_many :roles

name:string

profile.rb
belongs_to :user

latitude,latitude:float, address:string, city:string

role.rb
belongs_to :user
name:string
```

the problem I'm having is I need to filter the roles to say id => 3

so we have

```
@limitrole = User.includes(:profile, :roles).where('roles.id' => 3)
```

this returns an object of limited roles, now grab the profile that contains the geocode stuff

```
@profiles = @limitrole.collect { |user| user.profile }
```

This returns an object of addresses limited to the users role

But this won't work

```
@findlocations = @profiles.near('city, country', 20) (city and country being arbitrary values)
```

Yet this will work

```
@findlocations = Profile.near('city, country', 20)
```

@profiles should be the same as Profile (both objects) it's just @profiles has been filtered.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be railsy but this is how I got it to work

first grabbing the form fields

```
@findaddress = params[:profile][:profileaddress] + ", " + params[:profile][:profilecity]
```

Next I grabbed a list of the users based on their role

```
@limituser = User.includes(:profile, :roles).where('roles.id' => 3)
```

next using the geocoder (railscast #273) plugin I create a list of all the geocoded addresses that are near the locations specified in the form (@findaddress) and grab the user_id

```
@findlocations = Profile.near(@findaddress, 20).pluck(:user_id)
```

Now I can create a list of users filtered by their role and address specified by a form field

```
@filteruser = @limituser.where(:id => @findlocations)
```